# Moment.js add two weeks without changing hours

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

So my problem is this: When adding 2 weeks, instead of just adding weeks, moment also adds hours for some reason, how do I just change the date, while keeping the time the same?

```js
var firstDate = "2020-11-02;00:00:00";
var secondDate = moment(firstDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD;hh:mm:ss').add('2', 'weeks');

console.log(secondDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD;hh:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Output: `2020-11-16;12:00:00`

Wanted output: `2020-11-16;00:00:00`

I know I can extract the time from `firstDate` and later change the time of `secondDate` to that time, but I am wondering if there is a more clean way and also why this even happens.

Comment: Your display format has `hh` which is 12-hour format. There is no `00` with that, it's  instead `12 AM`. If you want `00`, then you should use the 24 hour format via `HH` - capitals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use capital `H` (24-hour time) instead of lower-case `h` (12-hour time).

```js
var firstDate = "2020-11-02;00:00:00";
var secondDate = moment(firstDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD;HH:mm:ss').add('2', 'weeks');

// output: 2020-11-16;12:00:00
console.log(secondDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD;HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```